# Grab whole word from between digits

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string that has one word and several numbers. I want to partition the string by the word. For example,

```
"100 1990 top 1000 500" #=> ["100 1990 ", "top", " 1000 500"]
```

I thought that this would work, but it doesn't:

```
'100 1990 top 1000 500'.partition(/[\ba-zA-Z\b]/) # => ["100 1990 ", "t", "op 1000 500"]
```

However, using Rubular, the regex above does match the whole word `"top"` (and only that word) given the above string.

What am I missing?

Comment: try to use `split` method on string.

Comment: `/[\ba-zA-Z\b]/` is incorrect. You'd want `/\b[a-zA-Z]\b/`.

Comment: @theTinMan, you forgot `+` and I don't think you want the word breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular example there is no need to use a regexp which are usually slower compared to simple string methods:

[`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) does exactly what you need:

```
'1990 top 1000'.split
#=> ["1990", "top", "1000"]
```

When you are interested in the substring on each side of the word, you might want to use that word as an argument to `split`:

```
'1990 top 1000'.split('top')
#=> ["1990 ", " 1000"]
```

Or just use this regexp:

```
'1990 top 1000'.partition /\b[a-zA-Z]+\b/
#=> ["1990 ", "top", " 1000"][
```

As Wiktor mentioned this regexp wouldn't match characters that aren't in the A-Z range. To also match unicode characters like Ä, ß or ç you might want to use the `[[:alpha:]]` character class:

```
'1990 äop 1000'.partition /\b[[:alpha:]]+\b/
#=> ["1990 ", "äop", " 1000"]
```

Read more about [Regexp character classes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need partition. I want to separate out the substrings on each side of the word.

Comment: But I don't know that the word will be 'top'. I just know that there will be a (whole) word with digits on either side.

Comment: Awesome!  I need to learn regex.  Still leaves the question of why it didn't work in Rubular. Is there a better Ruby regexp editor?

Comment: This  regex will not match words with Unicode letters like `français` correctly. I explained how your regex works at rubular. BTW, `\b+` makes no sense, placing a `+` quantifier on a zero-width assertion is incorrect.

Comment: You don't want the word breaks: `'7up 1000'.partition(/\b[[:alpha:]]+\b/) #=> ["7up 1000", "", ""]` vs `'7up 1000'.partition(/[[:alpha:]]+/) #=> ["7", "up", " 1000"]`.  (Tack on `.map(&:strip)` to remove extra spaces.)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches exactly one symbol, either `\b` (backspace, it is not a word boundary, because `\b` inside a character class loses its special meaning and becomes just an escape sequence) or an ASCII letter (one from `a-z` or `A-Z` ranges). So, rubular.com showed you have 3 separate matches. You can check it by yourself by placing a capturing group over your pattern (see [your regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/g8Fu8LvBHA)).

You may use `/\p{L}+/` regex (that matches 1 or more *letters*) with `partition`:

```
'1990 top 1000'.partition(/\p{L}+/)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/RH40ct)

If your strings contain only 1 word, this should work. BTW, *`\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter, not just ASCII*.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer what you are "missing", but what you are probably misunderstanding is the character range `[]` in regex. It expresses a single character. `[\ba-zA-Z\b]` means either a word boundary, a small letter, or large letter, (or redundantly, a word boundary). You are partitioning by a single such character, which is not what you want.

Comment: See @Wiktor's comments about the treatment of `\b` within a character class. For example `"abc def".partition([/\b/]) #=> ["abc def", "", ""]`, which is the return value you get whenever there is no match on `partition`'s argument.  And what is `\b`? `puts "cats\b and dogs" #=> cat and dogs`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You mean `/[\b]/`, I guess. And `\b` does not have meaning in a string. It is meaningful in a regex.

Comment: Yes, I meant `/[\b]/`. True, it has special meaning in a regex, provided it's not in a character class. `\b` in a string was an aside. `"\b".ord #=> 8` ("backspace"). That was new to me (or is something I'd forgotten).